# Filling in a stacked DataFrame with values from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I've got a stacked dataframe with 4 columns, with each column requiring a specific dictionary. For each column, i want the respective dictionary to fill in all of the rows it can.

This is the dataframe itself:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSpPC.png

and for the LB column, the dictionary `LB_data` must fill all of the values it can:

```
[{'Essendon': 1.32, 'St Kilda': 3.3},
 {'Carlton': 5.0, 'Port Adelaide': 1.16},
 {'Geelong Cats': 1.57, 'Melbourne': 2.36},
 {'Greater Western Sydney': 2.75, 'West Coast Eagles': 1.44},
 {'Brisbane': 1.95, 'North Melbourne': 1.85},
 {'Hawthorn': 1.38, 'Western Bulldogs': 3.0},
 {'Fremantle': 1.32, 'Gold Coast': 3.3}]
```

I've tried to create a new dictionary which includes the stacked rows however I'm not entirely sure over how to pass this into the DataFrame:

```
{'Essendon v St Kilda': {'Essendon': 1.32, 'St Kilda': 3.3}, 'Carlton v Port Adelaide': {'Port Adelaide': 1.16, 'Carlton': 5.0}, 'Geelong Cats v Melbourne': {'Geelong Cats': 1.57, 'Melbourne': 2.36}, 'Greater Western Sydney v West Coast Eagles': {'West Coast Eagles': 1.44, 'Greater Western Sydney': 2.75}, 'Brisbane v North Melbourne': {'North Melbourne': 1.85, 'Brisbane': 1.95}, 'Hawthorn v Western Bulldogs': {'Hawthorn': 1.38, 'Western Bulldogs': 3.0}, 'Fremantle v Gold Coast': {'Gold Coast': 3.3, 'Fremantle': 1.32}}
```

There are similar dictionaries for the other 3 columns.

How do I create the dictionaries in such a way that the data can easily be substituted into the DataFrame?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about what *format* the dictionaries should take, or how to get them into that format?

Comment: Yeah what format sorry. I should be able to work out how to do it myself. I'll make an edit of what I just tried as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your data should be in this form:

```
{column_1: {(l0_index_0, l1_index_0): value, 
            (l0_index_0, l1_index_1): value,
            (l0_index_1, l1_index_0): value...
            },
 column_2: {l0_index_0...
            }
 ...
 }
```

For example:

```
data = {'LB': {('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Brisbane'): 1, ('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Port Adelaide'): 2,
               ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'Fremantle'): 3, ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'St Kilda'): 4},
        'PB': {('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Brisbane'): 5, ('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Port Adelaide'): 6,
               ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'Fremantle'): 7, ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'St Kilda'): 8},
        'SB': {('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Brisbane'): 9, ('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Port Adelaide'): 10,
               ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'Fremantle'): 11, ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'St Kilda'): 12},
        'NEDS': {('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Brisbane'): 13, ('Brisbane v Port Adelaide', 'Port Adelaide'): 14,
                 ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'Fremantle'): 15, ('Fremantle v St Kilda', 'St Kilda'): 16},
        }

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Output:

```
                                        LB  PB  SB  NEDS
Brisbane v Port Adelaide Brisbane        1   5   9    13
                         Port Adelaide   2   6  10    14
Fremantle v St Kilda     Fremantle       3   7  11    15
                         St Kilda        4   8  12    16
```

Accordingly, since your input data is in four separate dataframes, it will be necessary to concatenate them in some way to respect this format.

Using `LB_data` defined in the question, we can define a simple function to transform it into data of the required format:

```
def transform(d):
    keys = list(d)
    combined = ' v '.join(keys)
    return {(combined, key): value for key, value in d.items()}

pd.DataFrame({'LB': {k: v for datum in LB_data for k, v in transform(datum).items()}})
```

Which gives this:

```
                                                                     LB
Brisbane v North Melbourne                 Brisbane                1.95
                                           North Melbourne         1.85
Carlton v Port Adelaide                    Carlton                 5.00
                                           Port Adelaide           1.16
Essendon v St Kilda                        Essendon                1.32
                                           St Kilda                3.30
Fremantle v Gold Coast                     Fremantle               1.32
                                           Gold Coast              3.30
Geelong Cats v Melbourne                   Geelong Cats            1.57
                                           Melbourne               2.36
Greater Western Sydney v West Coast Eagles Greater Western Sydney  2.75
                                           West Coast Eagles       1.44
Hawthorn v Western Bulldogs                Hawthorn                1.38
                                           Western Bulldogs        3.00
```

By performing the same operation on the other sets of input data and concatenating the results, you can get a dataframe of your expected format.

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you so much

Comment: How would I go about sorting the keys however? Some values aren't showing up in the dataframe because I've got Port Adelaide v Carlton for instance

Comment: Ah don't worry! Figured it out